# Introduction to Valued Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, model-theory

I'm looking for an introductory text on valued fields, to be used as the basis for a reading group for model theorists. Currently, I know of one such text, Valued Fields by Engler/Prestel. However, I'm unfamiliar with the book and have not been able to find any reviews for it.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The book of Engler/Prestel is a standard reference in the theory of valued fields. For learning about valuations and henselian fields especially in the context of algebraic number theory, the book *Algebraic Number Theory* [(link)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540653996) by J. Neukirch helped me a lot.